# from DataGridView saving to text file issue when saving date values on vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem. Whenever I save data into a text file from a DataGridView, the format of the date gets automatically converted to date along with time. It shouldn't be like that because the data from where the datagridview is basing from is only pure date but when I transfer it into a text file it automatically adds a time. It looks something like this:

```
246,4/20/2013 12:00:00 AM,01:00:00,p
```

How do I remove the time (12:00:00 AM) that comes along with the date?

These are codes for the datagrid:

```
Private Sub load_table()

    sConnection = New MySqlConnection
    sConnection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=cph;Convert Zero Datetime=True"

    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource


    Try
        sConnection.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from swipe_table"
        sqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, sConnection)

        SDA.SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

        sConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        sConnection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    sConnection = New MySqlConnection
    sConnection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=cph;Convert Zero Datetime=True"

    Dim SDA As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim bSource As New BindingSource
    Try
        sConnection.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from swipe_table"
        sqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, sConnection)

        SDA.SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)
        bSource.DataSource = dbDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bSource
        SDA.Update(dbDataSet)

        sConnection.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        sConnection.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

And these codes are for the saving to text file part:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim filename As String = String.Empty
    Dim sfd1 As New SaveFileDialog()

    sfd1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    sfd1.FilterIndex = 2
    sfd1.RestoreDirectory = True
    sfd1.Title = "Save Text File"

    If sfd1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If sfd1.FileName = String.Empty Then
            MsgBox("Please input filename")
        Else
            filename = sfd1.FileName.ToString
            Saveto_TextFile(DataGridView1, filename)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub Saveto_TextFile(ByVal dvList As DataGridView, ByVal filename As String)
    Dim strDestinationFile As String = "" & filename & ".txt"
    Dim tw As TextWriter = New StreamWriter(strDestinationFile)
    Dim LineToWrite As String = String.Empty

    Try
        For _Row As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            LineToWrite = String.Empty
            For _Column As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
                If DataGridView1.Rows(_Row).Cells(_Column).Value IsNot Nothing Then

                    LineToWrite &= "," & DataGridView1.Rows(_Row).Cells(_Column).Value.ToString
                Else
                    LineToWrite &= ","
                End If
            Next
            LineToWrite = LineToWrite.Remove(0, 1) 'remove the first comma
            tw.WriteLine(LineToWrite)
        Next
        tw.Flush()
        tw.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: show something that you have done so far

Comment: sorry I forgot, edited

Comment: You could check the Data Type for the fields it is adding a time to in the table design and ensure it doesn't include a time. You can also format those fields before you export them `Format([YourDateField],"mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: Where's the ideal place to put the 'Format' command? If you were to insert it on my code, where would you put it?

Comment: Can anyone help me please? I'm desperate. I tried inserting the format command but nothing happened.

Comment: If you tried and it didn't work then you did it wrong.  If you don't show us what you did then we can't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the type of the cell value...

```
For _Column As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
  If DataGridView1.Rows(_Row).Cells(_Column).Value IsNot Nothing Then
    If DataGridView1.Rows(_Row).Cells(_Column).Value.GetType Is GetType(Date) AndAlso CDate(DataGridView1.Rows(_Row).Cells(_Column).Value).TimeOfDay = New Date().TimeOfDay Then
      LineToWrite &= "," & CDate(DataGridView1.Rows(_Row).Cells(_Column).Value).ToShortDateString
    Else
      LineToWrite &= "," & DataGridView1.Rows(_Row).Cells(_Column).Value.ToString
    End If
  Else
    LineToWrite &= ","
  End If
Next
```

Comment: thank you sir! you answered well unlike the first answer who thinks everyone is as gifted as he is. I wouldn't have gotten this without your help, the codes are getting trickier.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "pure date".  The .NET `DateTime` type always represents a date and a time.  It's accepted that you can zero the time to represent just a date but the time portion is till there and you'll see it when you output the value using `ToString` with no parameters.  You should either call `ToShortDateString` or else call `ToString` and pass an appropriate format specifier, e.g. "d" for short system date format or "M/dd/yyyy" for US date format.

Comment: How would I call ToShortDateString sir? I'm sorry but I am new to programming and I am weak at it. Where amongst my code should I put it?

Comment: We're not here to teach you how to program.  We're here to answer specific questions about issues.  If you don't know how to call a method then read a tutorial.  Have you done any reading or looked for any examples of calling `ToShortDateString` in the five minutes between my answer and your comment?  The answer's no, so stop waiting for others to teach you the basics and start looking.  You may be new to programming but I assume that you've used a search engine before.  Make an effort.

Comment: @jmcilhinney if no-one answers questions about the basics, then a Google search won't find any answers about the basics!

Comment: (anyway, where to put the `ToShortDateString` call is not a simple question, since you need to know how to check the type of the cell and cast its contents)

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for your help anyway, someone answered my question already and he isn't as rude as you are. I did research but I just find it tricky nowadays and I don't know where exactly I should put it unless I saw an example of it. I am not asking you to teach me programming, I am asking for help on my problem because I already gave up because my inferior brain couldn't get it. You are one rude old man.

Comment: @SSS, are you really trying to suggest that there's no examples of `DateTime.ToShortDateString` out there?  As for how to determine what type the contents of a `DataGridViewCell` is, that's another topic and can be researched as an independent topic. Part of the problem is that people expect a magic solution to their specific set of circumstances instead of breaking a problem down and researching each part individually. The more people get coddled when doing that, the more they expect it next time and the less likely they will be to make additional effort in future.